# open file with shell() in R

Tags: windows, r, shell, cmd

I want to open a file in a windows program using R, but specifying the program rather than the default for the file extension, and for a file not necesarrily in my current R session home directory (this one `getwd()`)

From looking at the documentation, using `shell()`, should be the way, but I seem to have an issue with the way R references the home directory or the way I'm writing the string.

e.g.

This works ok in the cmd "run" in windows: excel e:\test.xlsx

but using this

```
route <- "e:\\test.xlsx"
shell(paste("excel " , route, sep=""), flag="")
```

seems to get to excel (excel copyright notice is printed), but also prints the home directory and doesn't open the file in `route`.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command does the same for me.  However, this works:

```
shell(paste("start", "excel", route))
```

Comment: Thanks. What does the flag switch do?

Comment: It's a shell argument.  The default is `/c` which is what you need (says to execute the following commands), so you actually exec `cmd.exe /c start excel <filename>`.